# An API is being hit when <Doclist/> component is rendered through "userlist.js" ,but not when the same component is rendered through "newuser.js"

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios, components

inside userlist.js the code looks like

```
const renderItems = ({item}) => {
  if (item !== undefined) {
      const user = {
        image:'https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar6.png',
        name: item.name,
        lastMessage: item.lastChat,
        time: item.latest_timestamp,
        seen: item.seen,
        id: item._id,
      };
  
      if(item._id!==userID)return <DocList user={user} nav={nav} sendToParents={fn} from="userlist"/>;
      else return null;
    }
    return null;
  };

  const DATA = [
    { 
      data: friends,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={{marginTop:53,marginBottom:130}}>
      {friends.length==0?
         <View style={{alignSelf:'center',marginTop:90}}>
         <Image style={{resizeMode:'stretch',width:350,height:220,alignSelf:'center'}} source={require('../../asserts/No_chats.png')} />
         <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontWeight:'bold',marginTop:10,color:'#838383'}}>No recent chats !</Text>
         <Text style={{textAlign:'center',textAlign:'center',width:300,alignSelf:'center',color:'gray'}}>Not yet started conversation? press the green + icon to see the list of users you can chat with.</Text>
       </View>
      :
      <SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={renderItems}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
        <View>{title}</View>
      )}>
      </SectionList> }
      
    </View>
  );
};
```

inside newuser.js it looks like

```
const handleRender = ({ item }) => {
    const user = {
      image: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar6.png',
      name: item.name,
      lastMessage: item.lastChat,
      time: item.latest_timestamp,
      seen: item.seen,
      id: item._id,
    };
    return (
      <DocList user={user} nav={nav} sendToParents={handleCallback} from="newuser" />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={docs}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          
        renderItem={handleRender}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The DocList component is:

```
import {socketSubsribe, socketIdentity, socketUnsubscribe} from './SocketServer';
import axios from 'axios';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {BASE_URL, BASE_URL1} from '../../Components/Urls';
import { nowTime } from '../../Components/Clock';
import socket from "../components/SocketServer";

const DocList = ({user, nav, sendToParents,from}) => {
  const [latestmsg,setLatestmsg]=useState(user.lastMessage);
  const [userImg,setUserImg]=useState(null);
  const [seen,setSeen]=useState(user.seen);
  const [roomID,setRoomID]=useState();
  let latmsg;
  // const textBold = user.seen ? 'normal' : 'bold';
  const textBold ='bold';
  const subscribe=async()=>{
    //await AsyncStorage.removeItem("chatUsers");
    const resultRoomidChat= await AsyncStorage.getItem(`${user.id}`);
      if(resultRoomidChat){
        const {roomId,chat}=JSON.parse(resultRoomidChat);
        console.log(roomId,"ROOMId");
        setRoomID(roomId);
      }
    const { userId,userToken} = JSON.parse(
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken')
    );
    const GET_IMAGE_URL=BASE_URL1+"/api/user/getUserImg";
    const resultUser= await axios.get(GET_IMAGE_URL+`/${user.id}`,{
      headers:{
        authorization:`Bearer ${userToken}`
      }
    });
    //console.log("RESULTUSER",resultUser.data.picture,typeof(resultUser.data.picture));
    if(resultUser.data.picture){
     // console.log("USER Image",resultUser.data.picture);
     let imgsrc=resultUser.data.picture;
    
    setUserImg(imgsrc);
    //console.log("IMGSRC",imgsrc);
    }
    socketIdentity(userId);
   //console.log("SUNSCRIBE IDENTITY");
    const object =await AsyncStorage.getItem(`${user.id}`);     
    if(object){
      //console.log("SUNSCRIBE OTHERUSER");
      const {roomId}=JSON.parse(object);
      socketSubsribe(roomId, user.id);
    } 
  }
  const handleRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const {userToken, userId} = JSON.parse(
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken'),
      );
      
        const URL= BASE_URL+'/api/chat/initiate';
        const data={
          userIds: [userId, user.id],
          type: 'customer-to-doctor',
        }
  
      console.log("1",URL, data);
      const res= await axios.post(URL,data,{
        headers:{
          authorization:`Bearer ${userToken}`
        }
      })
      console.log("2",res.data,res.status);
      if (res.data && res.status ) {
        const {chatRoom} = res.data;
        const id = chatRoom.chatRoomId;
        console.log("CHATROOM ID iS",id)
        
        const object1=await AsyncStorage.getItem(`${user.id}`);
        console.log("object1 ",object1);
        if(object1){
          const object=JSON.parse(object1);
          const modifiedObject={
            roomId:id,
            medium:'app',
            chat:[...object.chat]
          }
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(`${user.id}`, JSON.stringify(modifiedObject));      
          console.log("USER.ID",user.id,modifiedObject);
        }else{
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(`${user.id}`, JSON.stringify({roomId: id,medium:'app', chat:[]}));console.log("after setting ROOM ID");
        }

      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, '==>> error in app doclist');
    }
  };
 

  const call2doclist=async(msg,postedByUser,seen)=>{
    try{
     const {userInfo} = JSON.parse(
       await AsyncStorage.getItem('chatUsers'),
     );
     const {userId} = JSON.parse(
       await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken'),
     );
     //console.log("uI in DOCLIST");
     if(userInfo){
       console.log("hi call2doclist");
       let i=0;
       for(i=0;i<userInfo.length;i++){
         if(userInfo[i]._id==user.id){
           //console.log("hi3");
           console.log("POSTEDBYVUSER CHECK",postedByUser,userId,user.id);
           if(seen==true && postedByUser==userId){
             console.log('hi4');
            userInfo[i].seen=true;
            setSeen(true);
           }else{
            userInfo[i].seen=false;
            setSeen(false);
           }
           userInfo[i].lastChat=msg;
           setLatestmsg(msg);
             
           
           console.log("userInfo[i]",userInfo[i],seen);
           break;
          
         }
       }
       
       await AsyncStorage.setItem(
         'chatUsers',
         JSON.stringify({userInfo:[...userInfo]}),
       );
     }
     user.lastMessage=msg;
     setLatestmsg(user.lastMessage);
     
     console.log("SEEN",seen);
    }catch(e){
      console.log("Error in call2 inside doclist",e)
    }
     
   }
  const handlePress = async () => {
    setLatestmsg('');
    console.log(latestmsg,from);
    await handleRequest();
    if(from=="newuser"){
      sendToParents(user.id);
    
    }
    console.log("inside doclist",user);
    console.log("hey");
    nav.navigate('ChatSc', {name: user.name, id: user.id ,from:'app',call2doclist:{call2doclist}});

  };
 const updateChat=async(msg)=>{
  try{
    const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem(`${user.id}`));
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(
      `${user.id}`
    );

      data.chat.unshift({
      
        side:msg.side,
        text:msg.text,
        message_id:msg.message_id,
        time: msg.time,
      
    });
    //console.log("i saev");
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      `${user.id}`,
      JSON.stringify({...data}),
    );
  }catch(e){
    console.log("Error in updating chats",e);
  }
 }
 const update2=async(msg)=>{
   await updateChat(msg)
 }
socket.off('new message'+`${roomID}`).on('new message'+`${roomID}`,(data,err)=>{
    try{
      if(err){ console.log("error in socket recieving",err)}
      if(!err){
        console.log("inside DOCLIST for app");
        const msg={
          // postedByUser:data.message.postedByUser._id,
          message_id:data.message.postId,
          side:user.id === data.message.postedByUser._id ? 'left':'right',
          text:data.message.message.messageText,
          time:data.message.message.time,
          timestamp:nowTime()
  
        };
        update2(msg);
        call2doclist(data.message.message.messageText,data.message.postedByUser._id,false);
      }

    }catch(e){
      console.log(e,"Error in chatScreen of inside doclist ",e.message)
    }
   

});

  const subscribe2=async()=>{
     await subscribe();
    console.log("hi");
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
   subscribe2();

  },[]);
  
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handlePress()}>
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        {/* user Image */}
        <View style={{...styles.ImageContainer}}>
          <Image source={{uri:userImg?userImg:user.image}} style={{...styles.imageStyle}} />
        </View>
        {/* user data value */}
        <View style={styles.userContainer}>
          <View style={styles.userInfo}>
            <View>
              <Text>{user.name}</Text>
              <Text style={{fontWeight: textBold,paddingRight:30}}>{seen==false?latestmsg:''}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
            
          </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default DocList;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageStyle: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 70,
  },
  topContainer: {
    paddingLeft:10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    height: 78,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
  ImageContainer: {
 
    width: 70,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  userContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  userInfo: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```

through userlist.js the console.log prints 2, response data and status , but through newuser it doesn't print these things although it prints 1, URL, data. It means there's some problem there itself but in the former case, it does hit the API and logs in the backend too, but in the latter case it doesn't hit and doesn't log anything there in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the item parameter is correctly passed to the handleRender function in newuser.js. Also check in the Networks Tab in console whether is it actually hitting the API or because of authentication issue the call must be getting rejected.